# How to automatically reconnect Android devices with 'KDE Connect'?

Tags: android, kde-connect

I like **[KDE Connect](https://userbase.kde.org/KDEConnect)** and want to automatically re-/connect a former paired android device on start up, after suspend or standby mode.

I'm using

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:        12
Codename:       bookworm
```

and **Android-Version 11**. Workstation and mobile device are in the same network.

Every hint or work around is appreciated.